# Entity Framework AddOrUpdate not setting FK value on update

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I've inherited a project that uses EF 6.2 and the AddOrUpdate method during the Migrations Seed() process.

With a clean database, this code works just fine. Once there is data though, the update piece is giving me problems.

We add the new template as seen below. Then we add the template to the Event.Templates collection. On the ADD version of this, starting from a clean database or no database, this fills in the Template.Event_Id Foreign Key value as expected.

But during the Update, once Events and Templates exist, it adds the new Template but leaves the Event_ID as null. There are other examples that I've checked against and those seem to have worked, or someone may have manually edited the database after the fact.

Any idea why it's doing this?

```
Template NbCaseConfirmationCarrierSubmissionAppTemplate = new Template
{
    NotificationType = "app",
    TemplateName = "NB Case Confirmation of Carrier Submission App Template",
    TemplateSubject = @"@Model.EventData.CompanyName's enrollment has been submitted to @Model.EventData.CaseCarrier",
    TemplateBody = @"",
    JsonPayload = @"",
    TemplateHistory = new List<TemplateHistory>()
};

context.Templates.AddOrUpdate(x => x.TemplateName, NbCaseConfirmationCarrierSubmissionAppTemplate);


Event NbCaseConfirmationCarrierSubmissionEvent = new Event
{
    EventType = "NbCaseConfirmationCarrierSubmission",
    Description = "NB Case Confirmation Carrier Submission",
    ProgramId = "BM_CASE_CONFIRMATION_CARRIER_SUBMISSION_NOTICE",
    NotifySalesforce = true,
    Templates = new List<Template>
    {
        NbCaseConfirmationCarrierSubmissionEmailTemplate,
        NbCaseConfirmationCarrierSubmissionAppTemplate
    }
};            

context.Events.AddOrUpdate(x => x.EventType, NbCaseConfirmationCarrierSubmissionEvent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue. The core issue was that they built out the entity classes enough to get the database to build correctly, but they didn't include the FK object or ID on the Template class.

I had to add the below to the Template class:

```
public virtual Event Event { get; set; }

[Column("Event_Id")]
public int? EventId { get; set; }
```

Then I had to add the below to the DB Context OnModelCreating method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
     .HasRequired(x => x.Event)
     .WithMany(x => x.Templates)
     .HasForeignKey(x => x.EventId);
```

Then I had to rearrange the code I posted in the question to AddOrUpdate the Event before the Template, remove the entries in the Event.Templates, and assign the value to Template.EventId.